# Is there a package manager for Java like easy_install for Python?

Tags: java, package-managers

Is there a [package manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) for Java like [easy_install](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easy_install) for Python ?
I'm looking for a solution usable from the command line and not from an IDE.

Comment: What do mean with "package manager"? java libs are not installed into OS, just bundled with you app classpath.

Comment: As a python guy taking java on for the first time under professional dictates - I wish.  Something like NPM would be great.

Comment: Like Nuget for visual studio

Comment: I don't see this mentioned but if you use ubuntu most of the most common  packages are available like `apt install maven` or `apt install gradle`

Comment: This is not off topic to close, it is a valid question for python developers who try to write JVM languages.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[Maven](http://maven.apache.org/) does provide **dependency management** based on remote **repositories** (like the [central repo](http://search.maven.org/#browse)) that are browsable, [searchable](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#How_to_find_dependencies).

[Maven Ant Tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html) *(retired)* use Maven's repositories to provide dependency management and more to Ant builds.

[Ant Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) is another alternative to Maven Ant Tasks.

[MOP](http://mop.fusesource.org/) is another command line tool that leverages Maven's repository and dependencies.

Comment: MOP sounds interesting.
Have you tried it?

Comment: @systempuntoout Tried, yes. Used regularly, no. I actually work mostly with server sides apps and I do almost everything with Maven.

Comment: @systempuntoout Maven 2, of course :)

Answer (score 21):

Edit 2017-04-27: I have been disappointed by the lack of forward momentum for jpm4j, and the lack of community-centric development. So I invented a new tool called [jrun](https://github.com/ctrueden/jrun). I invite everyone to check it out. It has a narrower scope than tools like Python's `pip`, but it does let you execute Java code from remote Maven repositories in an easy-to-use manner.

---

Check out [JPM4J](https://www.jpm4j.org/). It is a project by [Peter Kriens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/243991/peter-kriens) (of BND fame). He [first proposed it last year](http://softwaresimplexity.blogspot.com/2012/04/just-another-package-manager.html), and as of this writing it has been around for a few months and is looking pretty impressive.

It was inspired by Node's npm, and like that tool, installation is a cinch:

OS X:

```
local   $ curl http://www.jpm4j.org/install/local  | sh
global  $ curl http://www.jpm4j.org/install/global | sudo sh
```

Linux:

```
curl http://www.jpm4j.org/install/script | sh
```

And Windows has a clicky installer, of course.

Then you install stuff similarly to other command-line package manager tools. E.g.:

```
jpm install org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all
```

The install command operates Maven coordinates. Basically, the JAR just needs a `JPM-Command` entry in its manifest, and `jpm` knows how to expose its main class as a command-line executable.

Personally I would really love to see the Java community get behind an effort like this. A really solid Java package manager is years overdue!

Comment: Would be nice if they added a chocolatey installer

Comment: As of today, the http://www.jpm4j.org site is down.

Comment: I have edited my post with information about a new project I have started called `jrun`.

Comment: Does `jrun` assume that the application has a `main()` method?

Comment: @DerekMahar You can optionally specify a main class as part of a `jrun` endpoint. If you leave off the main class, it will use the `Main-Class` defined in the artifact's JAR manifest.

Answer (score 4):

[Ivy from Apache](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/) is the closest thing I know of.